# PyQt5 DateEdit white background under arrows

Tags: python, background, pyqt5, qdateedit

is it possible to have a QDateEdit with custom arrows and set background and border color? I tried many options using setStyleSheet, but none worked.

My current code just changing the arrows and is bellow:

```
    QDateEdit {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 0 8px;
        selection-background-color: darkgray;
    }
    QDateEdit::down-arrow {
        image: url(arrow.png);
        max-width: 1px
    }
    QDateEdit::up-arrow {
        image: url(up-arrow.png);
        max-width: 1px
    }
```

This is how it looks now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXN5T.png

And this is how my comboBox looks and how should dateEdit looks too:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WykW1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QDateEdit` can be styled in the same way that a `QSpinBox` can.
There is an `up-arrow`, `down-arrow` control as well as `up-button`, `down-button`.

Setting the background an border color styles for the buttons should be set to each button sub-control.

From the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qspinbox), here are some examples of how to style a `QSpinBox`.

```
QSpinBox::up-button {
    subcontrol-origin: border;
    subcontrol-position: top right; /* position at the top right corner */

    width: 16px; /* 16 + 2*1px border-width = 15px padding + 3px parent border */
    border-image: url(:/images/spinup.png) 1;
    border-width: 1px;
}

QSpinBox::up-button:hover {
    border-image: url(:/images/spinup_hover.png) 1;
}

QSpinBox::up-button:pressed {
    border-image: url(:/images/spinup_pressed.png) 1;
}

QSpinBox::up-arrow {
    image: url(:/images/up_arrow.png);
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}

QSpinBox::up-arrow:disabled, QSpinBox::up-arrow:off { /* off state when value is max */
   image: url(:/images/up_arrow_disabled.png);
}

QSpinBox::down-button {
    subcontrol-origin: border;
    subcontrol-position: bottom right; /* position at bottom right corner */

    width: 16px;
    border-image: url(:/images/spindown.png) 1;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 0;
}

QSpinBox::down-button:hover {
    border-image: url(:/images/spindown_hover.png) 1;
}

QSpinBox::down-button:pressed {
    border-image: url(:/images/spindown_pressed.png) 1;
}

QSpinBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(:/images/down_arrow.png);
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}

QSpinBox::down-arrow:disabled,
QSpinBox::down-arrow:off { /* off state when value in min */
   image: url(:/images/down_arrow_disabled.png);
}
```

If you replace the `QSpinBox` with `QDateEdit` all of those controls should work identically.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added links to that documentation.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you. :) I tried to style it as a comboBox...